# How to set up a new virtual environment in PyCharm 2023.1.2 using Conda and specifying its location?

Tags: user-interface, pycharm, location, conda

How to specify the location of conda's new virtual environment in pycharm 2023.1.2?i donot see the option.by the way,i use the beta ui.

may be the beta UI? in the old edition,it has the option to specify the location.pls help